# Is there any numeric week number format which define week in many years?

Tags: php, date, week-number

With PHP date functions, we can easily use a week number which change 0 to 53. This count starts from zero each year.

I'm looking for a date format which give me a numeric value which is continuing each year without count reset.

**Example:**

```
this_week = 578 (this week is in 2015)
newt_week must be = 579 (even it's in next year)
```

Is there any pre-defined format for that purpose? If not, which approach can help me to find a custom solution?

Comment: When would this start? 2000?

Comment: I've got an idea, if we start counting in seconds from say, erm, 1st jan 1970 and use that as a standard count then count the weeks that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the PHP time function to convert to UNIX time (seconds since 1970-01-01). You can find the number of weeks since a given date by dividing by number of seconds in a week. In fact, the PHP documentation documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) shows an example very much like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `You can find the number of weeks since a given date by dividing by number of seconds in a week`. What is with daylight saving time, leap years, leap seconds?